# PHP Array manipulation need tips

Tags: php, arrays

I have arrays in one submission, please see below details:

```
array(5) {
  ["ambition_id"]=>
      array(2) {
        [55]=> string(2) "55"
        [60]=> string(2) "60"
      }
      ["target"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(8) "target 1"
        [1]=> string(8) "target 2"
      }
      ["strides"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1"
        [1]=> string(1) "1"
      }
      ["date"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(10) "2017-02-08"
        [1]=> string(10) "2017-03-08"
      }
      ["frequency"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=> string(1) "1"
        [1]=> string(1) "2"
      }
}
```

Actually, I have two tables in mysql, 'ambition' and 'target'. Ambition is a group of targets ('ambition_id' is foreign key in 'target' table). That array will be stored in 'target' table. That's why there is an 'ambition_id'

I've tried many times but failed (using foreach), now I need someone who can give me a help.

By brute force, It's easy! I solved it already but I need "more advanced" array manipulation.

How can I come up into this?

```
array(2) {
   [0] => array('ambition_id' => 55, 
                'target' => 'target 1', 
                'strides' => 1, 
                'date' => '2017-02-08', 
                'frequency' => 1
                ),
    [1] => array('ambition_id' => 60, 
                'target' => 'target 2', 
                'strides' => 2, 
                'date' => '2017-03-08', 
                'frequency' => 2)
}
```

Please do help, many thanks!

Comment: $final_array = array(array_column($array ,0),array_column($array,1));

Comment: @Anant The first sub array doesnot have `0`, `1` indexs. Need to convert it first.

Comment: @SougataBose  yes

Comment: I would go back and look at how you create the array and make that processing make an array that you want rather than fiddling this one

Comment: Also if you make you question readable, they will read it. If not they will just move on!

Comment: if your array structure is allways the same Anant's answer is a good place to start, but you would need to change the keys in "ambition_id" to be the same as the others (0,1). If the structure is different every time, you need to foreach the ambition_id array, add a counter, use that counter to access elements of other arrays, and store everything in a new array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly how is that not readable?

Comment: ah, my appologies than :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pivot your data:

```
$data = array (
    "ambition_id" =>
        array (
        55 =>  "55",
        60 =>  "60"
    ),
    "target" =>
    array (
        0 =>  "target 1",
        1 =>  "target 2"
    ),
    "strides" =>
    array (
        0 =>  "1",
        1 =>  "1"
    ),
    "date" =>
    array (
        0 =>  "2017-02-08",
        1 =>  "2017-03-08"
    ),
    "frequency" =>
    array (
        0 =>  "1",
        1 =>  "2"
    )
);

// pivot data
$pivot = array();
foreach ($data as $datum => $values) {
    $value_index = 0;
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $pivot[$value_index][$datum] = $value;
        $value_index++;
    }
}

print_r($pivot);
```

This assumes you only have two levels of data and that the data is well behaved.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best answer, but it solves your problem

```
<?php
$array = [
    "ambition_id" =>
    [
        55 => "55",
        60 => "60"
    ],
    "target" =>
    [
        0 => "target 1",
        1 => "target 2"
    ],
    "strides" =>
    [
        0 => "1",
        1 => "1"
    ],
    "date" =>
    [
        0 => "2017-02-08",
        1 => "2017-03-08"
    ],
    "frequency" =>
    [
        0 => "1",
        1 => "2"
    ],
];
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $kk => $vv) {
        if ($k == "ambition_id") {
            $result[] = array($k => $vv);
        } else {
            $result[$kk][$k] = $vv;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test https://3v4l.org/UdHH8

Answer (score 0):

Just use loop the array and user `array_values` to re-index the loop the inner array and store it into new array like below .

```
   <?php

    $new_array =array();

    foreach($array as $key1=>$row1 )
    {
       $ss =array_values($row1);
       foreach($ss as $key2=>$row2)
       {

           $new_array[$key2][$key1]=$row2;

       }

    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($new_array);

    ?>
```

**Output :**

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ambition_id] => 55
                [target] => target 1
                [strides] => 1
                [date] => 2017-02-08
                [frequency] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ambition_id] => 60
                [target] => target 2
                [strides] => 1
                [date] => 2017-03-08
                [frequency] => 2
            )

    )
```